# Confused regarding using "Interface" in symfony2 Doctrine

Tags: php, interface, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this class

`UserInterface ---abstract class User implements Userinterface --------
class Teacher extends User`

Now i am confused that what type of class i should expect in my php files

I mean in my arguments do i need to type

`Class Test(UserInterface  $user)`

`Class Test(User   $user)`

`Class Test (Teacher  $user)`   or `Class Test (Teacher $teacher)`

I am confused

Answer (score 1):

Use the most general one that fits your needs, as it makes your code more flexible. For example, if a method you need to call exists in `UserInterface`, use it; if, on the other hand, the needed method is defined in `User` or `Teacher`, use the corresponding one instead.

Expecting an interface is more flexible than expecting a class, because extending a class is not possible in cases of parallel hierarchies, while you can implement an interface in this case.